# HP DL380 G7 - Voodoo Technology

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-proliant, bios

I have a HP DL380 G7 which on boot gives the following message:

HP Proliant Voodoo Technology: NDA Required
 - Error: Processor does not support Proliant Voodoo Technology

I've searched the web high and low and can find no mention of this anywhere.

I purchased two of these servers from a reseller called ICC a few months back for a project. The project completed I've now sold on the servers but had a question back from one of the buyers.

This error doesn't affect the operation of the server in any way but I found it rather odd that I can't find anything about it online.

The error is at the BIOS POST check stage.

The servers are running BIOS V67 (03/30/2011).

Comment: How about some detail... where did you get the server from? Is it new to you? What is its history? Basically, what happened to prompt you to write this question?

Comment: See if this helps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VoodooPC. But it doesn't look like something that should be found on a server...

Comment: It looks like something HP were testing at one stage and the BIOS is looking for supporting hardware. Nothing to worry about but was just a little curious.

Answer (score 1):

The system is probably on a pre-release BIOS or could have been prototype hardware or CPU. The NDA and internal codename point to that. I've had systems in the G7 era with special CPUs and extensions, but have not seen that particular message.

Tell the purchaser to try to update to the [newest firmware](http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=4091567&swLangOid=8&swEnvOid=4103) for the platform, which appears to be [2013.07.02](http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=4091567&swItemId=MTX_c314c6ed9b6040f1b3e48649d5&swEnvOid=4103).